# How to increase size of OS disk in Windows Azure using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell-3.0

I want to increase size of OS disk in Windows Azure using Powershell or any other tool. Please help

Regards 
Umair

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? When you ask a question please be specific on what you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done this by using below command on windows azure powershell latest version. Please note old version of powershell doesnot support this command .

Update-AzureDisk -DiskName [Disk-Name] -Label [DiskLabel]-ResizedSizeInGB 1020

Answer (score 1):

### Resize the OS drive

Open your Powershell ISE or Powershell window in administrative mode and follow the steps below:

1. Sign-in to your Microsoft Azure account in resource management mode and select your subscription as follows:

   `Login-AzureRmAccount
   Select-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName 'my-subscription-name'`
2. Set your resource group name and VM name as follows:

   `$rgName = 'my-resource-group-name'
   $vmName = 'my-vm-name'`
3. Obtain a reference to your VM as follows:

   `$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName`
4. Stop the VM before resizing the disk as follows:

   `Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName`
5. And here comes the moment we’ve been waiting for! Set the size of the OS disk to the desired value and update the VM as follows:

   `$vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.DiskSizeGB = 1023
   Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VM $vm`

   > The new size should be greater than the existing disk size. The maximum allowed is 1023 GB.
6. Updating the VM may take a few seconds. Once the command finishes executing, restart the VM as follows:

   `Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName`

And that’s it! Now RDP into the VM, open Computer Management (or Disk Management) and expand the drive using the newly allocated space.

pasted from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-expand-os-disk